# Bittrex REST API for Python, I want to create an order using API v3 https://api.bittrex.com/v3/orders

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, http-post, bitcoin, rest

I need help to create orders using the bittrex version 3 REST API. I have the code below and I can't understand what is missing to work. 
I can make other GET calls, but I cannot make this POST request.
I don't know how to deal with the passing of parameters.

Official documentation at https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#tag-Orders.

```
def NewOrder(market, amount, price):
#print 'open sell v3', market
market = 'HEDG-BTC'#'BTC-'+market
uri = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/orders?'
params = {
    'marketSymbol': 'BTC-HEDG',#'HEDG-BTC', #market
    'direction': 'BUY',
    'type': 'LIMIT',
    'quantity': amount,
    'limit': price,
    'timeInForce': 'POST_ONLY_GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    'useAwards': True
}

timestamp = str(int(time.time()*1000))
Content = ""
contentHash = hashlib.sha512(Content.encode()).hexdigest()

Method = 'POST'
uri2 = buildURI(uri, params)
#uri2 = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/orders?direction=BUY&limit=0.00021&marketSymbol=HEDG-BTC&quantity=1.1&timeInForce=POST_ONLY_GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED&type=LIMIT&useAwards=True'
#print uri2
PreSign = timestamp + uri2 + Method + contentHash# + subaccountId
#print PreSign
Signature = hmac.new(apisecret, PreSign.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

headers = {
      'Api-Key' : apikey,
      'Api-Timestamp' : timestamp,
      'Api-Content-Hash': contentHash,
      'Api-Signature' : Signature
}

r = requests.post(uri2, data={}, headers=headers, timeout=11)
return json.loads(r.content)
```

> NewOrder('HEDG', 1.1, 0.00021)

And my error message:

```
{u'code': u'BAD_REQUEST', u'data': {u'invalidRequestParameter': u'direction'}, u'detail': u'Refer to the data field for specific field validation failures.'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the documentation that this body is expected by the api as `json` data:

```
{
  "marketSymbol": "string",
  "direction": "string",
  "type": "string",
  "quantity": "number (double)",
  "ceiling": "number (double)",
  "limit": "number (double)",
  "timeInForce": "string",
  "clientOrderId": "string (uuid)",
  "useAwards": "boolean"
}
```

and you are setting these values as `url params` that's the issue.

you need to do this:

```
uri = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/orders'

# NOTE >>>> please check that you provide all the required fields.
payload = {
    'marketSymbol': 'BTC-HEDG',#'HEDG-BTC', #market
    'direction': 'BUY',
    'type': 'LIMIT',
    'quantity': amount,
    'limit': price,
    'timeInForce': 'POST_ONLY_GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    'useAwards': True
}

# do rest of the stuffs as you are doing

# post payload as json data with the url given in doc
r = requests.post(uri, json=payload, headers=headers, timeout=11)
print(r.json())
```

If you still have issues let us know. If it works then please mark answer as accepted. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: follows the recommendations but now has an error INVALID CONTENT HASH

Comment: Certainly content hash needs to calculated correctly

Answer (score 0):

I made the following modifications to the code but started to give error in 'Content-Hash'

I'm assuming that some parameters are optional so they are commented.

```
def NewOrder(market, amount, price):
market = 'BTC-'+market
uri = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/orders'

payload = {
    'marketSymbol': market,
    'direction': 'BUY',
    'type': 'LIMIT',
    'quantity': amount,
    #"ceiling": "number (double)",
    'limit': price,
    'timeInForce': 'POST_ONLY_GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    #"clientOrderId": "string (uuid)",
    'useAwards': True
}
#ceiling (optional, must be included for ceiling orders and excluded for non-ceiling orders)
#clientOrderId (optional) client-provided identifier for advanced order tracking

timestamp = str(int(time.time()*1000))
Content = ''+json.dumps(payload, separators=(',',':'))
print Content
contentHash = hashlib.sha512(Content.encode()).hexdigest()

Method = 'POST'
#uri2 = buildURI(uri, payload)#line not used
print uri
#PreSign = timestamp + uri2 + Method + contentHash# + subaccountId
PreSign = timestamp + uri + Method + contentHash# + subaccountId
print PreSign
Signature = hmac.new(apisecret, PreSign.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

headers = {
      'Api-Key' : apikey,
      'Api-Timestamp' : timestamp,
      'Api-Content-Hash': contentHash,
      'Api-Signature' : Signature
}

r = requests.post(uri, json=payload, headers=headers, timeout=11)
print(r.json())

return json.loads(r.content)
```

> > > NewOrder('HEDG', 1.5, 0.00021)

{u'code': u'INVALID_CONTENT_HASH'}

Answer (score 0):

```
       Bittrex API via requests package PYTHON


        import hmac
        import hashlib
        import time, requests

        nonce =  str(int(time.time() * 1000))
        content_hash = hashlib.sha512(''.encode()).hexdigest()
        signature = hmac.new(
            '<SECRET_KEY>'.encode(),
            ''.join([nonce, url, 'GET', content_hash]).encode(),
            hashlib.sha512
        ).hexdigest()

        headers = {
            'Api-Timestamp': nonce,
            'Api-Key': '<API_KEY>',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Api-Content-Hash': content_hash,
            'Api-Signature': signature
        }

        result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```